# Syncing rigidbody MovePosition in FixedUpdate with an object that uses Translate() to move in Update

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two objects, one that uses physics and rigidbody2D MovePosition() in FixedUpdate(), and one that does not have a rigidbody2D and is moved around via Translate() in LateUpdate().

I am trying to get the object with the rigidbody2D to precisely follow the other object, but because the positions update at different times (LateUpdate() vs FixedUpdate()), there is obvious stutter.  I have worked around this somewhat by using Translate() on the rigidbody object during LateUpdate() but only IF a physics update has not occurred between the previous and current frames, but otherwise only using MovePosition() in FixedUpdate().  This seems to generally smooth things out and works OK, but I worry that at fast move speeds Transalte() will make the rigidbody object move through collisions, which is undesirable.

Is there a way to sync two objects like this without using Rigidbody movement on the second object?  If not, is there a way to force collision checking during the LateUpdate() call to Translate()?

Edit to add:  I neglected to mention a trivial solution of updating the second object in FixedUpdate() while still using Translate().  This solution is undesirable because the second object is part of a complex system that does not use physics and should not be limited by the physics update.  The first object with the Rigidbody is a standalone object so there is a lot more freedom in modifying its behavior.

Comment: I decided to re-implement the way the system works.  It became clear to me as I was asking the question that I was asking to build hacky stuff on top of hacky stuff.  I spent a couple of days to redesign how these objects behave and interact in a way where this hackiness is not necessary.  I'm going to leave the question up in case there is an answer and someone is interested in hacky approaches :)